# Manual rotation in easeljs/tweenjs

Tags: rotation, html5-canvas, createjs, easeljs, tweenjs

I've been having problems with rotating an object manually. What I want is for when a person double clicks on the object, it rotates by 20 (either side, I'm not fussy) once. If they click again, it rotates again by 20. However, it won't rotate at all at the moment (double click, or not). What am I doing wrong here?

```
var tri2 = new createjs.Shape();
tri2.graphics.beginStroke("#000").beginFill('#000').drawPolyStar(0, 0, 50, 3, 0, 270);

var draggerTri2 = new         createjs.Container();

draggerTri2.x = Math.random()*100;
draggerTri2.y = Math.random()*100;
draggerTri2.addChild(tri2);  

stage.addChild(draggerTri2);

draggerTri2.on("pressmove",function move(evt) {

evt.currentTarget.x = evt.stageX;
evt.currentTarget.y = evt.stageY;

stage.update();   

});

draggerTri2.on("dblclick", function rotate(evt) {

var tween2 = new TWEEN.Tween(draggerTri2,dataset)
          .to({left: "-20"}, 2000)
      .repeat(0)
      .onUpdate(function(draggerTri2){
        draggerTri2.left = Math.round(draggerTri2.left);
      })
     .start()

stage.update();   

 });

  stage.update();
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/AoifeMcNeill/pen/XqyWej?editors=0010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tween code is NOT TweenJS code. If you double click, you get a console error that TWEEN is not defined.

TweenJS code would look like this:

```
draggerTri2.on("dblclick", function rotate(evt) {
  var tween2 = createjs.Tween.get(draggerTri2, {override:true})
  .to({rotation:draggerTri2.rotation+20}, 2000)
  .on("change", function(event){
    var tween = event.target,
        draggerTri2 = tween.target;
    draggerTri2.rotation = Math.round(draggerTri2.rotation);
    stage.update();  // Only do this if nothing else is updating your stage
  });
});
```

You an also use the [RelativePlugin](https://www.createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/RelativePlugin.html) to rotate relative to your current rotation, instead of to an absolute number:

```
RelativePlugin.install();
var tween2 = createjs.Tween.get(draggerTri2, {override:true})
    .to({rotation:"+20"}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you! I've just started learning the createjs [and its' easeljs sub library], in the past 3 months, and only recently started on Tweenjs one, and there's not a huge amount of documentation on it, so was a bit lost.

I've put this as the answer.

Comment: We have tried to include extensive docs on the website (and in Github), as well as examples, and even a few tutorials. Interested to know what kind of material would help better - let us know on https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues or https://www.reddit.com/r/createjs/